# How can I set hidden_units to a list in Vertex AI?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-aiplatform

I am following [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mlops-with-vertex-ai/blob/main/02-experimentation.ipynb) notebook '02 ML Experimentation with Custom Model'.

When i try `vertex_ai.log_params(hyperparams)`, I get:

```
TypeError: Value for key hidden_units is of type list but must be one of float, int, str
```

but the next step `classifier = trainer.train` needs `hidden_units` to be a list.

(My version of `google-cloud-aiplatform` is `1.16.0`.)
Any help is appreciated.